# How to wrap a container element around inline-block children

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a container around two inline block elements. However the container collapses (the horizontal dashed line). How do I stop it from collapsing so that I can apply a background colour to the container. The structure is important and I want to avoid using flex-box. It is also important that the two coloured squares are right aligned and next to each other.

The aim is to create an absolutley positioned block element over a canvas element. With a descriptive name on the left and two buttons on the right. I have to work with what is there so a solution that involves as little change as possible would be great.

```css
    .header3 {
      width: 300px;
      background-color: lightgray;
      border: 1px dashed grey;
      position:relative;
      
    }
    
    .title3{
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      display:inline-block;
      vertical-align:center;
      background-color:#bada55;
    }
    
    .list {
      list-style:none;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      border:1px dashed green;
      position:absolute;
      display:inline-block;
      top:0px;
      right:0px; 
    }
    
    .item {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .item-1 {
      background-color: orangered;
    }
    
    .item-2 {
      background-color: skyblue;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
      <br>
      <div class="header3">
        <div class="title3">bollard name</div>
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="item item-1"></li>
          <li class="item item-2"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/timeband-it/pen/pYjNgB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you absolutely positioned your .title3 and .list elements which remove them from the normal flow.
If you want to achieve this layout use `float:right` on your `ul` and insert a `clear` in your `div (in the code below I achieved this using the`::after`:pseudo element of your`div`)

```css
* {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}

/* list */

.header3 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  position:relative;

}

.header3::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.title3{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:center;
  background-color:#bada55;
}

.list {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  border:1px dashed green;
  float: right;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header3">
    <div class="title3">bollard name</div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="item item-1"></li>
      <li class="item item-2"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```